# Image Downloader with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, imagedownload

I am beginner...
I have to write a program that should download an image from a URL (about 100 thousand) and store it in a database.  How can I do this with Spring Boot With REST??
(Or with multithreading)
I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the parenthetical "about 100 thousand" is that the number if images you will download at once, the maximum number of images you should support storing, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand what you are doing. As I understand it, you have 100,000 records for which you need to download an image. Is this something you will do just once or on some regular basis? What is the trigger for download(s) is this a scheduled operation or triggered by some user action?